# Calling R code from java library?

Tags: java

I'm new to statistics, is there any way through which codes written in R statistics software be called from java library.
I got some idea about JSC - "Java Statistical Class", but still not finding the way.

I found this under stackexchange: 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/open-source-java-library-for-statistics-at-the-level-offered-by-a-graduate-stati/60711#60711

Comment: This probably belongs on StackOverflow, since it's about coding, not directly about statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RCaller](http://www.mhsatman.com/rcaller.php)
I am working on this at the moment and some things work, some don't but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Probably rJava is the library you need.

The JRI component (formerly an independent project) lets you execute R functions from within Java. You'll have to translate your original R-code to your Java code using JRI's api, but that's reasonably straight-forward and the library performs fast.

You can install rJava from within R or on ubuntu as a package via apt.

I would be careful with the Java Statistical Classes. For me it calculated nonsense in some cases, so better cross-check the results with R should you decide to use that one.